# Mapper does not find another mapper it depends on

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two mappers, `MapperOne` and `MapperTwo`, where the latter depends on the former:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MapperOne {

    UserDTO convert(User user);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MapperOne.class)
public interface MapperTwo {

    @Mapping(target = "loginUser", source = "user")
    UserDTO convert(Login login);
}
```

`MapperTwo` works as expected, but let's assume a third mapper that uses `MapperTwo` like this:

```
import static org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MapperThree {

    default UserDTO convert(@NonNull final LoginWrapper loginWrapper) {
        final Login login = loginWrapper.getInstance();
        return getMapper(MapperTwo.class).convert(login);
    }
}
```

`MapperThree` doesn't work and I always get the following error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "com.mytest.mappers.MapperOne.convert(com.mytest.User)" because
> "this.mapperOne" is null

Comment: Could you maybe give a little bit more Context? `com.mytest.User`  suggests you are writing a test. Mapstruct behaves differently when there you use `componentModel = "spring"` and you start a Unit-Test without a spring context. In IntegrationTests it should not matter.

Comment: In Mapstruct, you can use the attribute "uses" in @Mapper (uses={dependmapper1.class,dependmapper2.class,} to list other mappers that the current mapper depends on. Below, I will demonstrate. Also,  componentModel=spring should be defined globally in your maven pom file or in gradle config, so you do not have to add that to every mapper.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `componentModel = "spring"` the you should not use `Mappers.getMapper`. Using usual `@Autowired` or dependency injection via constructor should work. This is propably why you are having problems in your case. Just using `uses = {SomeMapper.class}` is fine. Mapstruct will automatically use the Mappings of the "used" mapper when the Types are applicable.

If you want to really write the function within another Mapper then you should use an abstract class and Autowire the other Mapper as usual.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class MapperThree {

    @Autowired
    MapperTwo mapperTwo;

    UserDTO convert(@NonNull final LoginWrapper loginWrapper) {
        final Login login = loginWrapper.getInstance();
        return mapperTwo.convert(login);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use abstract class, you need to autowire via setter injection.  And default is not valid in an abstract class.

Comment: You are correct. The concept however should work. The defined methode in the abstract class can work with the injected mapper which is no longer null.

Comment: Using `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MapperTwo.class`  should produce the same result... but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Define a Property in pom.xml:**
Add a property to your pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
  <mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>spring</mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>
</properties>
```

**Configure the Maven Compiler Plugin:**
Add configuration to pass this property to the annotation processor so you do not have to include componentModel=spring in every mapper repeatedly:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <annotationProcessorOptions>
                    <mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>${mapstruct.defaultComponentModel}</mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>
                </annotationProcessorOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

MapperOne does not need to change.

```
@Mapper
public interface MapperOne {
  UserDTO convert(User user);
}
```

MapperTwo: Can you confirm that the desired return value is UserDTO and not LoginDTO or something similar?

```
@Mapper(uses = {MapperOne.class})
public interface MapperTwo {

  @Mapping(target = "loginUser", source = "user")
  UserDTO convert(Login login);
}
```

Assuming you need some converter method and want to depend on another mapper, you can define an abstract class and autowire via setter injection.

```
@Mapper(uses = MapperTwo.class)
public abstract class MapperThree {

  protected MapperTwo mapperTwo;

  @Autowired
  public final void setMapperTwo(MapperTwo mapperTwo) {
     this.mapperTwo = mapperTwo;
  }

   UserDTO convert(@NonNull final LoginWrapper loginWrapper) {
    final Login login = loginWrapper.getInstance();
    return mapperTwo.convert(login);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I confirm the desired return value is `UserDTD`. By the way, using `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MapperTwo.class` produces the same code and it doesn't work.